# IdentityServer4: Using refresh_token to get a new access_token when clients doesn't know the client_secret

Tags: identityserver4, refresh-token

Firstly: I can successfully make calls to

```
http://localhost:7791/connect/token POST
 grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token={refresh_token}
&client_id=resource-owner-client
&client_secret=secret
```

and this returns a new access_token, refresh_token, expires_in, and token_type.

However, I want to do it without a client_secret.
In my case my clients are remote applications that have been issued a starting access_token, refresh_token, etc.

using this call.

```
http://localhost:7791/connect/token POST
grant_type=password
&scope=arbitrary offline_access
&client_id=resource-owner-client
&client_secret=secret&username=rat&password=poison
```

The initial call is trusted and the secrets know, but downstream usage of the refresh_token should not require the client_secret.

How can I configure this or where would I have to code my own abstraction to make things work this way?

Comment: I did a code review of where it was validating the client, and the ability to do what I want has not been accounted for via some abstraction other than implementing my own IEndpoint and hooking the incoming call at the very start.  It bails out pretty early if the client is bad.  I was hoping my use case was not that uncommon.  Perhaps I will have to go down the custom grant path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box.

You could implement that using an extension grant.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html